# How can we optimize this SQL query. It's taking lot of time

Tags: optimization

```
Select 
    t.id, t.col1 
from 
    schema1.table2 t
where 
    t.col1 LIKE '%dsfs%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fsd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fsd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fsd%'     
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sdfsh%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sdgsnjfwfsd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sfsdfs%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%dhdfh%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sdfsh%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%hdfh%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%dj%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%utkg%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fn%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%fsd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%gwr%'   
    or t.col1 LIKE '%s%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%dfgsjr%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%ursdfgsd%'     
    or t.col1 LIKE '%gs%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%gtsg%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sdgsnjfwfsd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%sd%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%gs%'    
    or t.col1 LIKE '%dg%'
```

Actually I need to find data that contains at least one of these keywords, and data is in millions, so, can we optimize this code so that it quickly retrieves data in minutes.

Note: keywords list is huge. And can be increased.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server** (you didn't specify that clearly), then you're out of luck - using the `LIKE '%....%'` approach makes it **impossible** for SQL Server to use any indexes to improve performance. The only feasible option would be to look into **fulltext searching** in SQL Server which *might* give you decent performance

Comment: For something odd like this - full text as mentioned by @marc_s is properly your best bet. Otherwise - a chance - and this is maybe - is to put all the keywords into a table, and then join the two tables together. It might help. Another possibility is to precalculate the result using a scheduled job, so you don't have to look it up run-time. Also - consider doing this outside SQL Server. Even if data is in the millions, there are other tools that do such string look up much better than a relational database which is not build for this type of work

Comment: this is for mysql workbench actually. can we do something like indexing? also can u tell me how can i write full text searching query?